# Android not connecting to WIFI Programmatically

Tags: android, esp32

```
 package com.example.wifiscanner;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.Network;
import android.net.NetworkCapabilities;
import android.net.NetworkRequest;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.telecom.Connection;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AfterPermissionGranted;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AppSettingsDialog;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {

    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private ListView listView;
    private Button button;
    private int size = 0;
    private List<ScanResult> results;
    private ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    private String ssid = "SLT-FIBRE";
    private String password = "VMEKF27*";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                scanWifi();
            }
        });

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listview);
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);

        if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {

            Toast.makeText(this, "Wifi is disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);

        }

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayList);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        ConnectToNetworkWPA(ssid,password);
        scanWifi();


    }

    public void startScan() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                scanWifi();
            }
        }, 5 * 1000);
    }


    @AfterPermissionGranted(123)
    public void scanWifi() {

        String[] perm = {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE};

        if (EasyPermissions.hasPermissions(this, perm)) {

            arrayList.clear();
            registerReceiver(wifiReceiver, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION));
            boolean scanStarted = wifiManager.startScan();

            if (scanStarted) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Scanning false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Toast.makeText(this, "PERMISSIONS HAVE BEEN GRANTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        } else {

            EasyPermissions.requestPermissions(this, "WE REQUIRE THESE PERMISSIONS FOR THE APP TO FUNCTION", 123, perm);
        }

    }


    BroadcastReceiver wifiReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            results = wifiManager.getScanResults();

            unregisterReceiver(this);

            for (ScanResult scanResult : results) {
                arrayList.add(" " + scanResult.SSID + "   " + scanResult.frequency + "    " + scanResult.level + "   " + scanResult.BSSID);
                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


            }

        }

    };

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        EasyPermissions.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults, this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsGranted(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {

        scanWifi();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPermissionsDenied(int requestCode, @NonNull List<String> perms) {

        if (EasyPermissions.somePermissionPermanentlyDenied(this, perms)) {
            new AppSettingsDialog.Builder(this).build().show();
        }

    }

    public void ConnectToNetworkWPA(String SSID, String password) {
        try {
            WifiConfiguration conf = new WifiConfiguration();
            conf.SSID = "\"" + SSID + "\"";   // Please note the quotes. String should contain SSID in quotes

            conf.preSharedKey = "\"" + password + "\"";

            conf.status = WifiConfiguration.Status.ENABLED;
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedGroupCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.GroupCipher.CCMP);
            conf.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.WPA_PSK);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.TKIP);
            conf.allowedPairwiseCiphers.set(WifiConfiguration.PairwiseCipher.CCMP);


            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(conf);

            Log.d("connecting", conf.SSID + " " + conf.preSharedKey);
            Log.d("after connecting", conf.SSID + " " + conf.preSharedKey);


            wifiManager.disconnect();
            wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
            wifiManager.reconnect();
            Log.d("re connecting", SSID + " " + conf.preSharedKey);

            final NetworkRequest requestForWifi =
                    new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                            .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                            .build();

            final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

            final ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback  networkCallbackWifi = new ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback(){

                @Override
                public void onAvailable(@NonNull Network network) {

                    
                }

                @Override
                public void onLost(@NonNull Network network) {

                    
                }
            };

            connectivityManager.requestNetwork(requestForWifi, networkCallbackWifi);



        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.getMessage();
            ex.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

    public void BroadCast() {

        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(false);
        }

        WifiConfiguration netConfig = new WifiConfiguration();

        netConfig.SSID = "HM3355";
        netConfig.allowedAuthAlgorithms.set(WifiConfiguration.AuthAlgorithm.OPEN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.RSN);
        netConfig.allowedProtocols.set(WifiConfiguration.Protocol.WPA);
        netConfig.allowedKeyManagement.set(WifiConfiguration.KeyMgmt.NONE);

        try {
            Method setWifiApMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("setWifiApEnabled", WifiConfiguration.class, boolean.class);
            boolean apstatus = (Boolean) setWifiApMethod.invoke(wifiManager, netConfig, true);

            Method isWifiApEnabledmethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("isWifiApEnabled");
            while (!(Boolean) isWifiApEnabledmethod.invoke(wifiManager)) {
            }
            ;
            Method getWifiApStateMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApState");
            int apstate = (Integer) getWifiApStateMethod.invoke(wifiManager);
            Method getWifiApConfigurationMethod = wifiManager.getClass().getMethod("getWifiApConfiguration");
            netConfig = (WifiConfiguration) getWifiApConfigurationMethod.invoke(wifiManager);
            Log.e("CLIENT", "\nSSID:" + netConfig.SSID + "\nPassword:" + netConfig.preSharedKey + "\n");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e(this.getClass().toString(), "", e);

        }

    }
}
```

I am trying to programmatically connect my android app to my esp32 wifi chip but it does not work. Code compiles and runs without a problem but it does not connect to the specified network. No error is shown, even when I debug I see the ssid and password correctly going through the methods but cannot understand why it will no connect to the esp32 , my PC can connect when I use these credentials.

Answer (score 0):

What you have currently will set up the credentials and connection for a Wi-Fi network but if there are no outstanding requests for that network, the Networking portion of Android will tear it down (or never bring it up).

If you want to also bring up a Wi-Fi network, you need to both setup the credentials as you have currently and request Wi-Fi like so:

```
final NetworkRequest requestForWifi =
  new NetworkRequest.Builder()
  .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
  .build();

final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)
  context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

final NetworkCallback networkCallbackWifi = new NetworkCallback() {
  @Override
  void onAvailable(Network network) {
      // Once this callback triggers, you've connected to Wi-Fi
      Toast.makeText(context, "CONNECTED TO TRD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }

  @Override
  void onLost(Network network) {
      // Triggers when this network is lost.
      Toast.makeText(context, "NOT CONNECTED TO TRD", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
};

connectivityManager.requestNetwork(requestForWifi, networkCallbackWifi);
```

Finally, change this method signature to be void like so and remove any logic you had around the previous `boolean` return value:

```
public void ConnectToNetworkWPA(String networkSSID, String password)
```

You won't know that you are connected until the `networkCallbackWifi#onAvailable` callback triggers therefore having the other method return true/false was incorrect.

Comment: I added it this way

Comment: No, I am having an issue. See I added the code you gave me to the "connect to WPA method" I hope that is correct. Next, the code compiles and runs without error but not working as intended. Can we add a check and enable wifi as well to this ?

Comment: Oh is the issue that wifi is disabled? Can you enable wifi on the device and see if the code works as expected then?

Comment: This way we can confirm that enabling wi-fi will solve the issue before we add code to do so.

Comment: I made sure the wifi was enabled on the device but still the same result , I think the issue lies in the way my code is executed, could you run it on your end please ? . Also I reposted the code at the top after adding your suggestion , please check if that is correct.

Comment: In `public void onAvailable(Network network)`, this will trigger with the network that is returned. Can you perhaps add a log there (or use toast like you are in other places) to confirm that a network is being returned and available? This will let you know if Android is even finding an available Wi-Fi network at all to connect to. If it isn't, then most likely there is an issue with how you are configuring the Wi-Fi network.

Comment: Btw, `onAvailable` is what will trigger once you are connected so that's really what you want to wait on to confirm you've actually connected to Wi-Fi.

Comment: Hi, I still need help with this, it's not working. Are you there?

Comment: Hi Dirk, yes, you'll need to wait on the `ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback#onAvailable` method to trigger before you can be certain that you are connected. Looking at your code, you seem to return true outside of that block. That isn't correct since you aren't guaranteed to be connected to a network at that point.

You should wait for `onAvailable` to fire with a network at which point you'll know you are connected.

Comment: Thank you for your input and time. If you could share a code stub please. of, how to connect to android WIFI.  I can even change my target SDK if necessary.  I just need a working code piece to use to quickly prototype my app.

Comment: Hi @Dirk , I made some updates to my code snippet. You should show the toast in the `NetworkCallback` and additionally, remove any logic tied to a returned boolean as I mention in the answer above.

Comment: Thank you soo much , let me go through and make the changes.

Comment: I made the adjustments as mentioned but it still does not connect. Also the debugger shows the network ID as -1. Any advise bro ?

Comment: Can we have a chat sometime bro ?, I am getting some odd behavior. I created a separate app with the connection code. On available in triggering only when the network is available. That does not confirm if it is connected to the Wifi network  BUT ONLY THAT THE WIFI LISTENER IS ON.

Comment: The network code is -1, so it's not connecting to the AP. Any way I can check if it is an issue with the credentials provided?

Comment: Try this; forget all Wi-fi networks on the device and see if it works then. The vast majority of devices can only connect to a single Wi-fi AP at a time. You can then test if that works and go from there.

Comment: It looks like you could also use a WifiNetworkSpecifier as part of your NetworkRequest. Here is some more info but short version is that you set the ssid, passphrase similar to a suggestion and pass that into your NetworkRequest:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiNetworkSpecifier.Builder

Comment: Thnk you soo much , let me try this out.